# EF Core get data that updated out of the DbContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, entity-framework-core

I have this code in my "Department Form"

```
    private readonly SIMContext _SIMContext;
    private Department model;
    public Frm_Department(SIMContext SIMContext)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _SIMContext = SIMContext;
    }
```

And this is the method that get data from database I added to load event
I have BindingSource component "dataBindingSource" that assign to gridControl DataSource

```
    private async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
            // Call the LoadAsync method to asynchronously get the data for the given DbSet from the database.
            await _SIMContext.Departments.LoadAsync().ContinueWith(loadTask =>
            {
                // Bind data to control when loading complete
                dataBindingSource.DataSource = _SIMContext.Departments.Local.ToBindingList();
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    }
```

all my CRUD operations work fine (using DbContext).
Now to the problem:
If I add or remove records directly(Manually) to the database (not using DbContext)  and if I call LoadDataAsync method I get all records without any problem.
But when I edit any record(Manually) (not using DbContext) and then call LoadDataAsync method I get old values not updated one.
How can I resolve this problem?.
I try:

```
dataBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
var state = _SIMContext.Entry(model).State;
state = EntityState.Modified;
```

but without any success.

I am using EF Core 3.1.15 with .Net 4.7.2

Comment: Try `_SIMContext.ChangeTracker.Clear()` before loading entries from Database.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv unfortunately, this is not possible for me I am using EF Core 3.1.15 and this option was introduced in EF Core 5 Preview 7

Comment: So then you have to recreate DbContext.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I am afraid not possible to I am using Dependency injection

Comment: Try the following `((Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager)_SIMContext.GetService<IStateManager>())).ResetState();`